# Selenium with C# - certain functions not working on Chrome browser version 90 but works fine for my teammates on their machine

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The code below runs fine when my teammate runs on her machine but errors on this line when I run on my machine. It mouse over an element and clicks on the first option in there. Our chrome version are same. I restarted my machine, re-installed Chrome, killed all active processes.. still doesn't get past this. Is there anything specific I should be looking for? Checked all existing extensions and no dodgy ones in there.

```
public static void MouseOveronElementandClick(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement ele)
    {
        waitTillElementExist(ele, WaitElement());
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        a.MoveToElement(ele).Build().Perform();
        //a.Click().Perform();
        SleepTimeOut(2000);
        IJavaScriptExecutor ex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
    }
```

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwYxa.jpg)

Disabled all extensions and ran again.. still the same

Comment: Can you please tell us what are the errors?

Comment: What if you disable all extensions?

Comment: Why are you performing the click with JavaScript instead of C#?

Comment: It fails even before that on line a.MoveToElement(ele).Build().Perform();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your element [ele] is "not interactable" when you're calling Perform(). Might be timing differences or different window sizes with your teammate's machine, or who knows. Try a Thread.Sleep() before your MoveToElement(), or stepping through code and seeing if the element does in fact look interactable. If it works when you step through code slowly, then it's a timing problem.

Comment: I have tried to debug and can confirm it's not a timing issue. Also, the very first line of the function waits for the element to exist.

Comment: Also, I ran this script on different screen sizes.. laptop screen and monitor

Comment: You keep saying the element "exists". "Existing" is not the point. The element can "exist" and still be not *interactable*, e.g. if it's covered up by another element.

Comment: Tried this. I can also see it's interactable, I can click on it when debugging. Tried different time for wait

public static void MouseOveronElementandClick(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement ele)
        {
            waitTillElementExist(ele, WaitElement());
            Actions a = new Actions(driver);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            a.MoveToElement(ele).Build().Perform();
            //a.Click().Perform();
            SleepTimeOut(2000);
            IJavaScriptExecutor ex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
        }

Comment: Re "I can click on it when debugging": So you're clicking on *something*, but how do we know you're clicking on the actual element [ele]? If [ele] is covered by another transparent element, then it might look to you like you're clicking on [ele], but you're actually clicking on the transparent covering element, which I think would cause the behavior you're describing.

Comment: An update on the issue - I cloned the repo and ran from there and totally unexpected but it worked fine. Still fails for the old one though but I am happy I have a solution. Thanks everyone for your inputs.